# Azure search service loads from one pc/network but hangs from another

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I recently started learning Azure with a free subscription. From a PC in my office, when I select "Search services", it tries to load for about a minute and says : "Oops! Could not create Azure search service. Something went wrong".

In notifications it says: "Refresh the browser to try again.
Microsoft_Azure_Search extension failed to load"

From my mobile though (i.e. a different device/network), I successfully created a Search service from the portal using the same login.

From my office PC, I was then able to select/load that Search service, but when I tried to add an index, it again tries to load for a while and comes up with same error. Whereas it again works fine from any of my personal devices.

I have uploaded some images into Blob storage successfully from my office PC, but issue seems to be with only Search service at the moment (haven't tried other services yet).

Can there be anything to do with browser/network/security that is blocking Search services to work in Azure portal from my office network? Or something else?

Browser: Google Chrome, Microsoft edge
OS: Windows 10

Comment: Hello, I am Nate from Azure Search. Could you send me the service name to nateko@microsoft.com so we can take a look at logs on our end?

Comment: Hi Nate, Many thanks for responding. I deleted the search service I had issue with and created a new one. Don't remember the name, sorry. I created it with Azure Microsoft account svktejasvi@outlook.com - not sure if this helps. FYI, managed to get this resolved by following the steps mentioned in the answer. If you ask me, it would help if Azure provides a more meaningful error such as "This link is not accessible" or something. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get this resolved. Below are the steps performed:

1. In Google Chrome, press Ctrl + Shift + I (OR) got to Ellipsis (3
   vertical dots on top right) -> More tools -> Developer tools - This
   will show network log in the right pane
2. Click on the search service link (or can click anything that is hanging)
3. You should see some entries in red in network log. Right click on a red entry -> Copy -> Copy link address
   For eg: I noticed all my red entries were pointing to: https://stamp2-search.azureedge.net/Content/Dynamic/LOYEVB9GHX9E.js
4. Contact network administrator to enable access to this link i.e. unblock it